# Bronze script on Chinese Ge (Characters identified: 之戈)

Tags: translation, character-identification, word-requests

[image][image: Ge]

Ancient Spring and Autumn/Warring States Period Chinese Ge (pole weapon) said to have been unearthed at an ancient community burial area along the present day Thai/Cambodia border near Aranyaprathet, Thailand. Current site input indicates characters are Bronze script. Similar characters can be seen on the bottom portion of a Ge pictured on https://www.chinafetching.com/sun-tzu

[image: Ge]

Comment: The characters look like 「之先」 to me. Would you be able to take a more focussed and higher resolution image for the second character, without the bright image enhancements?

Comment: it’s in bronze script, not seal script, most likely, an artefact produced between spring & autumn period, and warring states period (bc -770 to bc -221)

Comment: Additional photos added. Do you have a possible English translation for this Bronze script? The web reflects Bronze script to be a very complex and changing writing style used in ancient China.

Comment: Did the other side have any writing? Or do both sides have the same characters?

Comment: Only one side has wording. Cannot see any other markings on it.

Comment: I tried to clean up first picture, 2nd word, for you. Difficult as bronze has flaked off over time.

Comment: Thank you, but I’m out of ideas. Maybe someone else will have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 1):

the top character looks like “ㄓ” (之) in bronze script:

[image]

in the book 殷周金文集成, entry 11604 “蔡侯產劍”, the top left character

[image: 9]

or, the artefact “蔡侯產戈“, with characters “蔡侯產之用戈”

https://theme.npm.edu.tw/3d/Content.aspx?sno=04009242&l=1&q=&cat=&p=1&fromCnt=0

the character “之” in this one is “embellished” with “蔡國鳥蟲書特色”

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

The characters are 「㞢（之）戈」, which is an incomplete inscription. For example, 「XX之戈」 means *[Dagger-axe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger-axe) of XX*, so you have a proper noun or person's title missing from the inscription.

---

As the characters are meant to be in a [bird seal script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird-worm_seal_script), you can compare what you have with an inscription in that style. In this style, birds may be drawn as part of the actual character; for example, 「戈」 might look like

<kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 戈]
王子戈
[集成11207](https://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=11207&jgwfl=)</kbd>

In the full inscription of 《殷周金文集成》11207 (below), which says 「王子㞢用戈」 (*Dagger-axe for the use of* 「王子」), characters which have extra bird decorations surrounding the characters are circled in blue.

[image: 王子戈]

Comment: Thanks for all the assistance on translation. Purchased from reputable dealer in Thailand. Said to be found at an ancient burial site along with Jade items. Seller has little further information. Have another Ge found in same area, belonging to the later Han Dynasty.

Comment: Zhou dynasty Ge's are also on display in a museum in the Thai province of Loei, near the Thai/Lao border. This may suggest Chinese Ge's were carried in ancient times by Chinese travelers/traders as defensive weapons.